# How to save data to S3 from Rstudio on amazon web services

Tags: r, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, rstudio

I am using `Rstudio` on `Amazon Web Services`

I am storing files as part of the `RStudio` environment with the root of RStudio environment being called `"~Home/Myproject"`

I want to create a website in Rstudio using `rmarkdown::render_site()`. This creates html from `.Rmd` in the folder that I run the command from.

Because I use `S3` to host my website I would love for the generated files to be transferred to the directory this is stored in, on `S3` but a) I don't know how to get the directory path and b) how can I create the transfer in R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am also trying something similar :)

so far the best solution i have found is use of [cloudyr](https://github.com/cloudyr.)

You can install the aws package only with the following

```
install.packages("awspack", repos = c(cloudyr = "http://cloudyr.github.io/drat", getOption("repos")))
```

After that all you need is

```
Sys.setenv(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXX",
       AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

`library("aws.s3")`

`put_object(file = "YourFileName", object = "TheObjectNameInsideS3", bucket = "YourBucketName")`

This is very simplified version for test run of course, and you would definitely like to use **.Renviron** to store your **Sys.env**  data and not put them in script itself. These details again  [you can find in here](https://github.com/cloudyr/aws.s3)

hope that helps.